# Long invalid input crash - Angular form validation

Tags: regex, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an input with email pattern validator. (regex `^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$`)

If I type a long invalid email the form will crash. 
Surprisingly it will work fine for long valid input.

Has anyone experienced this before? Please share your workaround if you have.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how the regex is being used? Also, just how long is "long"? No crash for relatively short invalid email addresses?

Comment: I would suggest to experiment with the pattern shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @kshetline Yes, short email like 10 or 15 characters works fine. I tested with "thisismyveryveryveryverylongemail" and it starts lagging since "long" and officially crash when i reach "email".

Comment: @wp78de thanks, that pattern also fail for 30+ characters

Comment: All of them? There are many varieties in the answers of the linked question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It was actually because of another dependent input also have wrong regex that crash the system. Correct regex can be found here http://emailregex.com/ or the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: [`^\w+(?:[\.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[\.-]\w+)*(?:\.\w{2,3})+$`](https://regex101.com/r/XJmtDz/5/)

The crashing has to with the efficiency of your regex. In particular, those `?` after the `[\.-]` are unnecessary and causing many more repetitions than necessary. Some regex works well with matching solutions, but [catastrophically backtrack](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html) when presented with a string that doesn't match.

---

**Edit: These other two solutions won't work for Angular because it is Javascript regex, but they're still useful for general reference.**

Best, using [possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html): [`^\w++(?:[\.-]\w++)*@\w++(?:[\.-]\w++)*(?:\.\w{2,3})+$`](https://regex101.com/r/XJmtDz/1)

2nd best, with [atomic groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html): [`^(?>\w+)(?:[\.-](?>\w+))*@(?>\w+)(?:[\.-](?>\w+))*(?:\.\w{2,3})+$`](https://regex101.com/r/XJmtDz/3)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your regex and it still crash when it reaches 30+ characters. I will have a look at the links.

Comment: Sorry for not investigating deeply enough. It turned out to be a dependent input having wrong regex. Your answer is correct.